# Implication of proper containment of zero-dimensional varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $I$ and $I_{1}$ are zero-dimensional ideals in a polynomial ring (by which I intend that the affine varieties $\mathcal{V}(I)$ and $\mathcal{V}(I_{1})$ are each finite sets of isolated points).  What, if anything, does the containment $\mathcal{V}(I_{1}) \subset \mathcal{V}(I)$ imply about the initial ideals of $I$ and $I_{1}$?  In particular, is it true then that every standard monomial of $I_{1}$ is a also a standard monomial of $I$ with respect to a fixed term order?

Comment: It implies $\sqrt{I} \subset \sqrt{I_1}$. What's a standard monomial of an ideal?

Comment: Will: Standard monomial is a standard piece of terminology in Grobner basis theory. The initial ideal $in(I)$ is always generated by monomials, and therefore a basis for the quotient $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/in(I)$ are those monomials which are NOT in $in(I)$. These are called the standard monomials.

Comment: Sorry if I was inaccurate or not precise with the terminology.  I take "standard monomial" to mean the monomials that aren't in the initial ideal $in_{<}(I)$ or equivalently the basis of $R/I$.  

Comment: @OP: If the ideals don't have to be radical ideals, then this fails even in one variable: Take $I_1=(x^n)$, $I=(x\cdot (x+1))$. Standard monomials of $I_1$ are $1,x,\ldots, x^{n-1}$, but the standard monomials of $I$ just $1,x$. If you assume that the ideals are radical ideals, then $I \subset I_1$  and hence all assertions you make are true.

Comment: Florian: Thanks very much for the information.  In the cases I was looking at the ideals were, in fact, radical.  

Answer (score 1):

For radical ideals, this is true. By the Nullstellensatz, we have $I\subset I_1$. So the initial ideal of $I$ is contained in the initial ideal of $I_1$. (This is obvious from the construction.) So, conversely, the set of standard monomials of $I$ contains the set of standard monomials of $I_1$. (This is obvious from the definition of the standard monomials.)